# A datetime format

Tags: php, datetime

I need a way to make the datetime format looks like this : " 2013-10-23T12:30 "

I did it this way but it's not working:

```
 echo "<input name='showdatetime' type='datetime-local' id='showdatetime' value='" . date( "Y-m-dAh:i" , $show->datetime ) . "'><br/>";
```

Thank you

Comment: no output...the datetime input is empty...this is why i need to make my datetime in this format "2013-10-23T12:30" so the datetime shows, by default, in the input

Comment: If the output is empty then `$show->datetime` is probably blank. Have you verified it has a value? What value does it have?

Comment: the value shown is "1970-01-01AM01:33" but its not true date...i dnt know why

Comment: That's probably because `$show->datetime` is not a unix timestamp

Comment: Why don't you try with [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)?

Comment: well, my main idea is that i have a page for an admin to edit shows for movie in theaters...i need the admin, when editing a show, to see the datetime...so i need a way to make the datetime in database to looks like "2013-10-23T12:30" so it will be shown in the input and admin can edit it

Comment: That is ISO8601 formatting.  And it's been asked a few times already.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/903203/634824) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7367953/634824)

Comment: what's the value of `$show->datetime`?

Comment: @MattJohnson im very newbie in it...and i didnt rly understand what should i do...can u help more plz

Comment: Does date( "Y-m-dAh:i" , strtotime($show->datetime) ) help?

Comment: So, you told us the date shown is 1970-01-01AM01:33. Is that a correct format? Is that a correct date? What is your issue?The date or the format. If your problem is the date, you need to provide us with more information. Because the property $show->datetime seems do not have a valid date to be formatted. The code I wrote in my answer is showing the current date in the input.

Comment: this is the datetime in database :2013-04-02 02:00:00
and this is the code
  echo "show datetime :";
  echo "<input name='showdatetime' type='datetime-local' id='showdatetime' value='" . date( "Y-m-dAh:i" , strtotime($show->datetime) ) . "'><br/>";

now if i put in the value field like this format "2013-10-23T12:30" it will be showed in input field correctly

so my idea is to convert the datetime to smth like this for the correct datetime 2013-04-02T02:00

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = getdate();

echo "<input name='showdatetime' type='datetime-local' id='showdatetime' value='" . date( "Y-m-d h:i A",$date[0] ) . "'><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\` to escape characters, like the T.  So you want the following format:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i')
```

See [Example 2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#example-675) in the PHP date documentation