# jQuery time ago format plugin

Tags: jquery, mysql, time, timestamp

I'm thinking about using this plugin http://timeago.yarp.com/ to return date values to time ago.

But it required dates to be in this format  **ISO 8601**: 2008-07-17T09:24:17Z

That's where I'm confused as my dates are stored in a mysql database as a timestamp like this 2011-12-23 12:51:09

Could anybody help me distinguish the difference between the two timestamp types because the jQuery plugin wont work with my current timestamp formats (2011-12-23 12:51:09)

Comment: how are you getting them from mysql? what's in between?

Comment: A mysql query and then a while loop

Comment: yes but what is the language?

Comment: PHP I think I just need to convert the timestamp to  ISO 8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using php to query your mysql you can use this:

[How to display a date as iso 8601 format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903203/how-to-display-a-date-as-iso-8601-format-with-php)

or if you want to handle it in javascript, take a look at here:

http://webcloud.se/log/JavaScript-and-ISO-8601/