# How can I load all events on calendar using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

I want to load all events on FullCalendar using AJAX when I clicked **next-previous-button**  in `agenda-views`.

I guess, when will click on **next-previous-button** then I'll send current `date('y-m-d')` to `url: 'fetch-events.php'` then it will return `event{ id: ,title: , start: , end: , allDay: }` format data for rendering on calendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: false,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: false,

    events: // on-click next-previous button load events using Ajax
    // post date using Ajax, then query to fetch all events and return data             
});
```

JSON not working in my case

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the FullCalendar Online Documentation

> FullCalendar will call this function whenever it needs new event data.
>   This is triggered when the user clicks prev/next or switches views.
>
> This function will be given **start** and **end** parameters, which are
>   [Moments](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/Moment/) denoting the range the calendar needs events for.
>
> **timezone** is a string/boolean describing the calendar's current
>   timezone. It is the exact value of the [timezone](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/timezone/timezone/) option.
>
> It will also be given **callback**, a function that must be called when
>   the custom event function has generated its events. It is the event
>   function's responsibility to make sure **callback** is being called with
>   an array of [Event Objects](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).
>
> Here is an example showing how to use an event function to fetch
>   events from a hypothetical XML feed:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                start: start.unix(),
                end: end.unix()
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[Source](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/)

---

I made some little changes:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'schedule.php/load',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                start: start.format(),
                end: end.format()
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                if(!!doc.result){
                    $.map( doc.result, function( r ) {
                        events.push({
                            id: r.id,
                            title: r.title,
                            start: r.date_start,
                            end: r.date_end
                        });
                    });
                }
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Notes:** `start` and `end` **MUST** be [**ISO 8601**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903206/662581). Another change was the use of `format` instead of `unix` (this made easier for me to deal with the code-behind)

Comment: There are more examples and explanations on the Source-link

Comment: Why do you use double negation in !!doc.result?

Comment: How do I reload the events

Comment: @SbonisoMarcusNzimande you could refresh all the content, if it's what you need.

Comment: @MichelAyres The problem was not refreshing, I was showing the calendar according to filters. This means I was getting the events from different links this caused a problem in duplicating the events

Comment: @SbonisoMarcusNzimande create a new question with your code and specify the needs and problems that you're facing. Otherwise, we'll fill up this comment session to solve your problem =)

Comment: @MichelAyres does this code prints also the events in the calendar? cause in my case it does not

Comment: This info is a bit out of date. Since V4 of full calendar, the parameters which enter the specification to `events` function are different. Both start and end dates are fields of the 1. parameter. Docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Answer (score 3):

There is a built in option avaliable

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    events: '/myfeed.php'
})
```

more details https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Answer (score 1):

```
This is perfect way to load data properly.

// if you want to empty events already in calendar.
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');

$.ajax({
    url: 'ABC.com/Calendar/GetAllCalendar/',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: { Id: 1 },
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, err) {
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});

/* initialize the external events
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
$('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {
    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
    var eventObject = {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
    };
    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);
    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });
});

/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //isRTL: true,
    buttonHtml: {
        prev: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        next: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    //obj that we get json result from ajax
    events: JSON.parse(obj)
    ,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

fullCalendar already uses ajax, so you don't have to type it. When I was starting to implement fullCalendar I used the solution of the most voted answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25404081/3927450

but then I could prove, that fullCalendar is in charge of making the ajax call the times the view changes without you having to do anything. I find this plugin very useful, although the documentation did not seem very clear to me.

So this code:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'schedule.php/load',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
```

is exactly this:

```
events: schedule.php/load,
```

you only have to provide the url. Off course you have to deal with a proper JSON response from the server. Or if you need more params you can do it like this:

```
events: {
url: '/myfeed.php',
method: 'POST',
extraParams: {
  custom_param1: 'something',
  custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
},
failure: function() {
  alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
},
color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
```

}

Comment: you cannot add header with this :) Correct me if i am wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var events= '';
    $.ajax({
      url: '/eventoscalendar',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        events= JSON.stringify(data);
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            displayEventTime: true,
            selectable: true,
            droppable: false,
            events: JSON.parse(events)
        });
      }
    });

y en /eventoscalendar 

public function eventoscalendar()
  {
        $events[]= [
                "title" =>'Meeting',
                "start"=> date('Y-m-d'),
                "allDay"=> false,
                "url"=> 'http://google.com/'                    
        ]; 
        return JsonResponse::create($events, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json; charset=utf-8' ));
    }
```