# Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i have a problem when i'm trying to put the events on the calendar, an error show:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/getAllCitas",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (doc) {
          var events = [];
          doc.forEach(function (evt) {
            events.push({
              title: evt.paciente,
              start: evt.date,
              end: evt.date,
            });
          });
          console.log(events);
          callback(events);
        },
      });
    },
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Object.success (citas.js:179)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

event result. The doc is a json that have more infomation i only need the information like it is in the event.

```
0: {title: undefined, start: "2021-03-18", end: "2021-03-18"}
1: {title: undefined, start: "2021-04-02", end: "2021-04-02"}
2: {title: undefined, start: "2021-04-02", end: "2021-04-02"}
3: {title: undefined, start: "2021-04-06", end: "2021-04-06"}
4: {title: undefined, start: "2021-04-05", end: "2021-04-05"}
5: {title: "603fd0e423f0d241ecfdd337", start: "2021-04-06", end: "2021-04-06"}
6: {title: "Carlos", start: "2021-04-08", end: "2021-04-08"}
```

I need your help, thanks

Comment: Are you sure this `events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {` is correct? What if you try `console.log(start, end, timezone, callback);` as the first line in the events function; do you see what you expect to see?

Comment: ƒ () {
            if (!isResolved) {
                isResolved = true;
                success.apply(this, arguments); // eslint-disable-line prefer-rest-params
            }
        } ƒ () {
            if (!isResolved) {
                isResolved = true;
                if (failure) {
                    failure.apply(this, arguments); // eslint-disable-line prefer-rest-params
   … undefined

Comment: when i do the console.log i get its result, and the callback is undefined

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Can you link me to the part of the docs where you got that way of setting up the events from?

Comment: Looks like you borrowed some code from an example which relates to an older version of fullCalendar. Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function to see the latest version of the callback, and then you can adjust your code accordingly. Always read the manual.

Comment: i got the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019130/how-can-i-load-all-events-on-calendar-using-ajax -Chis G

Comment: That post is 9 years old! And notice the totally different jQuery-related syntax for declaring the calendar in general. So yeah would have been good to double check against more recent info. Glad you solved it now though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution, the callback like you said was from an old version. Now its successCallback, i change it and now it works, this is the new code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/getAllCitas",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (res) {
          var events = [];
          res.forEach(function (evt) {
            events.push({
              title: evt.paciente,
              start: evt.date,
              end: evt.date,
            });
          });
          successCallback(events);
        },
      });
    },
  });
  calendar.render();
});
```

Thanks