# fullcalendar - referencing in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I'm trying to use fullcalendar in a web app. I'm creating it using the following...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('rcalendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            start: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay saveEvents',
            center: 'title',
            end: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
        },
        customButtons: {
            newEvent: {
                text: 'add new reminder',
                click: function () {
                    alert('clicked custom button 1!');
                }
            },
            saveEvents: {
                text: 'save reminders',
                click: function () {
                    getDates();
                }
            }
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        editable: true,
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',
        selectable: true, //can click to set event
        eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            meridiem: 'short'
        },
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: '/Content/JSON/OpsReminders.json',
                color: 'blue',
                textColor: 'white',
                editable: 'true'
            }
        ]
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

Initially the calendar displays fine and has all the events from the JSON file. However when I add another event to the JSON file in the background I cannot get the calendar to refresh.

I've been trying.....

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/OpsAdmin/SaveReminders/",
    data: {"groupId": '@Model.OpsAdminGroup', "adminId": '@Model.OpAdministrator', "targets": objectStr, "date": eventDate, "time": eventTime, "datetime": eventDateTime, "repeat": rpt, "mon": mon, "tue": tue, "wed": wed, "thu": thu, "fri": fri, "sat": sat, "sun": sun, "msg": msg },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.saved) {
            hideModal();
        }  
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    },
    error: function (errorData) { onError(errorData); }
});
```

but the problem seems to be that I cannot get a reference to the calendar. '#calendar' seems to return nothing. Can anyone suggest any ideas why I can't get a reference to the calendar and confirm if I'm doing this the right way in the first place?

Comment: Maybe this question will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019130/how-can-i-load-all-events-on-calendar-using-ajax

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar` makes no sense, and should be throwing a console error in your browser. FullCalendar isn't a jQuery object (at least, not since version 4 was released, anyway). `calendar` is the reference to your calendar object in the code (because you wrote `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar...`). `calendar.refetchEvents()` is what you needed to write.

Comment: I'm using v3.9. If I try using calendar.refetchEvents() it errors and states "calendar is not defined". If I use $('#calendar')...... it does not error but is always null.

Comment: You can't be using version 3.9. If you were, `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar` wouldn't work at all. It must be v4 or higher. Please double-check.

Comment: `If I try using calendar.refetchEvents() it errors and states "calendar is not defined"`...presumably then, `calendar` is simply out of scope when you tried to use it. Make sure its scope extends to everywhere you need to access it. If that involves making it global... well it's not ideal in some ways but it's a nice easy quick solution

Comment: Don't know if this is the factor but I'm using the NuGet package version in VS and it definitely states it's a jQuery plugin and version 3.9?

Comment: Well if you're managing get the calendar displayed on the page then you _must_ be loading a higher version into your page - check what `<script` tags are actually present, and what files they point to. (I guess it's possible you're _also_ loading the 3.9 version into the page at the same time, but the simple fact is that the `new FullCalendar...` code you've shown _cannot_ work with 3.9)