# Use PHP to create timestamp in specific format

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a name for the timestamp format below? How would I go about using PHP to reproduce the time and date now in the same format?

```
2012-11-15T17:30:47-05:00
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe that is an ISO 8601 time format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 8601 format was added to the `date()` function in PHP 5 so you can use:

`date('c');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be ISO 8601 format, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601. Look at this to display a date in that format: [How to display a date as iso 8601 format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903203/how-to-display-a-date-as-iso-8601-format-with-php)