# Convert date string to format ISO php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to convert this date in string format iso format to save in mysql.

```
string(16) "25/02/2015 11:10"
```

Comment: And have you tried anything? I think a quick google search would turn up enough results. Put some effort before asking for help (especially for such a simple task). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How many [duplicates of this exact question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+date+php) have you failed to find?

Comment: Checkout `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a date as iso 8601 format with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903203/how-to-display-a-date-as-iso-8601-format-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('25-02-2015 11:10'));
```

You need to use dashes instead of the slashes.

Comment: as you would with variables? I'm new to php

Comment: Of course you can replace the 25-02-2015 11:10 with the variable holding the datetime value.
If you found this helpful, don't forget to mark this as an answer.

Comment: try what you say puts me 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: you need to replace '/' with '-' first.