# Changing time format

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have the following php:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'dfd_ModificationTimestamp',true); ?>
```

It outputs dates as the following: `13/06/2015 11:02:18`

I am not sure how to change it to "3 days ago" or "2 month ago" etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: See examples in http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: See a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416697/converting-timestamp-to-time-ago-in-php-e-g-1-day-ago-2-days-ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the wordpress function [human_time_diff](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff)

Example:

```
//Get your date
$date = get_post_meta($post->ID,'dfd_ModificationTimestamp',true);

//Convert it to a unix time stamp
$timestamp = strtotime($date);

//Print a nice string showing how long ago that was
echo human_time_diff( $timestamp, current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago';
```

Comment: I had no idea that existed! Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$dateString = get_post_meta($post->ID,'dfd_ModificationTimestamp',true);
/* @var \DateTime $date */
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $dateString);
```

Now $date is DateTime object. You can modify it as you wish.

For example, you need 3 days ago from your date value(13/06/2015 11:02:18)

```
$date->modify('-3 days'); // $date becomes 10/06/2015 11:02:18
```

or if you need 2 months ago from your date value(13/06/2015 11:02:18)

```
$date->modify('-2 months'); // $date becomes 13/04/2015 11:02:18
```

To print $date value after modify, use:

```
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php for more custom information.

Comment: lol - one of us clearly misunderstood, but I'm actually not sure who :p

Answer (score 1):

I know you tagged this PHP but you can do this with javascript using the timeago plugin.

`<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>`

is converted into

`<abbr class="timeago" title="July 17, 2008">7 years ago</abbr>`

You need to format the time in ISO_8601 format too, something like this would do it:

`echo (new DateTime('17 Oct 2008'))->format('c');`

Sources:

http://timeago.yarp.com/

[How to display a date as iso 8601 format with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903203/how-to-display-a-date-as-iso-8601-format-with-php)

Comment: I would look at Mikk3lRo's answer first - I didn't realise WordPress had a ready made function for this :)