# Convert timestamp into 2016-12-24T14:11:00Z

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Hi I'm trying to convert my result out of a timestamp field into a formated way.

So from '2016-12-24 14:11:00' to '2016-12-24T14:11:00Z'

What is the easiest way to do so?

Comment: What is that date format? It's pretty close to `iso 8601` there might be a predefined format for it. If not you could build it yourself with the `date` function. `date('Y-m-dTH:i:sZ'`. ISO example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903203/how-to-display-a-date-as-iso-8601-format-with-php

Comment: Please find below link for PHP:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php

Comment: Is your time zone already UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ISO 8601` format which can be achived by date with `c` param.

```
echo date('c', strtotime('2016-12-24 14:11:00'));
```

but if u want exactly that format you could personalize it

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('2016-12-24 14:11:00'));
```

If `z` letter means something then probably you need to find proper parameter on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Hi Robert, the 2nd example you gave did the trick, thank you very much.

Comment: Of course, this is correct if and only if `14:11` is already UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(replace(`date_field`,' ','T'),'Z')
```

Comment: So what happens if the hour field doesn't have a leading 0? Hmm? :)